# SLLN of Markov chains .

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1$, $X_2$,... be a finite state, irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain with initial state $X_0=i$. It is known that 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{P}\Big\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n I\{X_t=j\}=\pi(j) \Big\} = 1,
\end{equation}
where $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function and $\pi(j)$ is the stationary distribution of state $j$.

**Question:** Is the above also true if the state of the Markov chain is observed at arbitrary time instances (for example recording only every second state transition of the chain $X_1, X_3, X_5,...$)?
To put more formally, I'd like to know if the following is also true :
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{P}\Big\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n I\{X_{\tau(k)}=j\}=\pi(j) \Big\} = 1,
\end{equation}
where $\{\tau(k)\}$ is any infinite strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: If the sequence depends on the Markov chain, then no (in general). But for any fixed sequence I think it's true.

Comment: I'm also interested in the case where the sequence can depend on the Markov chain. I have been trying without success to come up with a Markov chain and sampling rule (sequence that may depend on the Markov chain) for which the above wouldn't obviously hold.

Comment: Try $(\tau(k))$ the sequence of times when the chain visits a given state.

Comment: Thanks p.s. and Did! I see now. Like @p.s. said, in general if the sequence depends on the Markov chain, almost sure convergence to the stationary distribution is not obtained.